# Calculate expected value and variance - example problem

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

There are 50 bars in Beer City. Every weekend the Ancient Society of Beer Lovers randomly chooses 3 bars to visit. Assuming that the choices every weekend are independent, calculate expected value and variance in number of bars visited at least once during 10 consecutive weekends.

I have literally no idea how to tackle this and it seems pretty basic example problem of variance/expected value. Could anyone help?

Comment: Expected value is relatively easy if you consider the probability that an individual bar is never visited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of bars visited at least once is $50$ minus the number of bars never visited, so we can calculate the expected value and variance of the latter.

Let $I_k$ be an indicator variable that is $1$ if bar $k$ is never visited and $0$ otherwise. Then we want to know the expected value and variance of $S=\sum_kI_k$.

The probability for one particular bar to never be visited is $p_1=\left(\frac{\binom{49}3}{\binom{50}3}\right)^{10}=\left(\frac{47}{50}\right)^{10}$. The probability for two particular bars to never be visited is $p_2=\left(\frac{\binom{48}3}{\binom{50}3}\right)^{10}=\left(\frac{47\cdot46}{50\cdot49}\right)^{10}=\left(\frac{1081}{1225}\right)^{10}$. Thus, the expected value is

\begin{eqnarray}
E[S]
&=&
E\left[\sum_kI_k\right]
\\
&=&
\sum_kE\left[I_k\right]
\\
&=&
\sum_kp_1
\\
&=&
50p_1
\\
&=&
50\left(\frac{47}{50}\right)^{10}
\\
&=&
\frac{47^{10}}{50^9}
\\
&=&
\frac{52599132235830049}{1953125000000000}
\\
&\approx&
26.93
\end{eqnarray}

and the variance is

\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{Var}[S]
&=&
E\left[\left(\sum_kI_k\right)^2\right]-E\left[\sum_kI_k\right]^2
\\
&=&
\sum_{j,k}E[I_jI_k]-\sum_{j,k}E[I_j]E[I_k])
\\
&=&
\sum_{j=k}E[I_jI_k]+\sum_{j\ne k}E[I_jI_k]-\sum_{j,k}E[I_j]E[I_k])
\\
&=&
50p_1+50(50-1)p_2-(50p_1)^2
\\
&=&
50(50-1)p_2-50p_1(50p_1-1)
\\
&=&
50(50-1)\left(\frac{1081}{1225}\right)^{10}-\frac{47^{10}}{50^9}\left(\frac{47^{10}}{50^9}-1\right)
\\
&=&
\frac{20007424621745238891781620924108115919925351951}{6211904899255558013916015625000000000000000000}
\\
&\approx&
3.22\;.
\end{eqnarray}